# What is the significance of component type and element type with respect to Arrays and Collection?

Tags: java, jvm

I was reading the [JVM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.4) and came across these two terms. 
What purpose these two serve in java language? Is there any significance of these for a programmer?

Comment: That second paragraph seems to explain all of that.

Comment: As explained in the same spec: An array type consists of a component type with a single dimension (whose length is not given by the type). The component type of an array type may itself be an array type. If, starting from any array type, one considers its component type, and then (if that is also an array type) the component type of that type, and so on, eventually one must reach a component type that is not an array type; this is called the element type of the array type. The element type of an array type is necessarily either a primitive type, or a class type, or an interface type.

Comment: Things are not very clear there, that's why I posted for a better explanation.

Comment: So, to put it simply, an element type is the type of anything that you put in an array that is not an array itself. The type of an innermost element in a possible hierarchy of nested arrays.

Comment: Very simply, an array can contain components or elements. Elements are individual primitives/class types/interface types, that are not arrays. Arrays can contain other arrays and those arrays can contain other arrays and so on but finally the inner most array should have something which is not an array and that is the element type.